# Close all (keep-alive) socket connections in tornado?

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

I'm running a set of tornado instances that handles many requests from a small set of keep-alive connections. When I take down the server for maintenance I want to gracefully close the keep-alive requests so I can take the server down.  Is there a way to tell clients "Hey this socket is closing" with Tornado?  I looked around and `self.finish()` just flushes the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, I hit on a solution for the kind of graceful shutdown I needed (note that this may *only* work with Tornado 3.2, as it depends on the request having a connection and checking for the `no_keep_alive` attribute.  Ultimately, there's no need to close a connection unless it's actively sending data (so stray existing connections don't really matter).

1. I set up a variable on the application that notes whether the application is shutting down.
2. In `initialize()` I check for this and if we are shutting down, I set the `Connection: close` header to comply with the RFC and then also set `self.request.connection.no_keep_alive = True` to force the connection to close before reading any more data but after the request is finished.

Relatively simple - looks something like this:

```
class GracefulRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        if self.application.is_shutting_down:
            self.set_header('Connection', 'close')
            self.request.connection.no_keep_alive = True
```

Answer (score 1):

`finish()` doesn't apply here because a connection in the "keep-alive" state is not associated with a `RequestHandler`.  In general there's nothing you can (or need to) do with a keep-alive connection except close it, since the browser isn't listening for a response.

Websockets are another story - in that case you may want to close the connections yourself before shutting down (but don't have to - your clients should be robust against the connection just going away).

Comment: I get that about `finish()`, what do I need to do on the Application object to close connections? I understand that it's not a huge issue to just suddenly shut down, but I'm wondering if there's a way to instruct tornado to close all open connections.

Comment: There's not currently any way to close all open connections except by shutting down the process.

Comment: Okay, thanks - that's the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: with Tornado 4 keeping track of all connections, you could just iterate over `app._connections` and close each one, right?

Comment: `HTTPServer._connections` is not a public attribute, but there is now a close_all_connections function you can use (note that it's a coroutine so it returns a Future you must wait on)